# C# Generic.ForEach not work? or EF easy way to exclude properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need clear some propery from List

CategoryAccount is class

Get List

```cs
List<CategoryAccount> ret = context.CategoryAccounts.ToList();
```

Clear with ForEach

```cs
//Clear Accounts poperty to null
//Accounts is List<Acccount>
ret.ForEach(x => x.Accounts = null);
//Clear Owner poperty to null
//Owner is class Owner 
ret.ForEach(x => x.Owner = null);

//In result
ret[0].Account != null
ret[0].Owner != null
```

Or exclude property in context.CategoryAccounts.

I don't want use `Select(x => new { prop1 = x.prop1, prop2 = x.prop2? ///}` - too many properties in model must be included.

Comment: Is `CategoryAccount` a struct?

Comment: CategoryAccount is class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be using lazy loading. You have to trigger load before assigning any values to navigation properties. You can do it using `Include`.

```
List<CategoryAccount> ret = context.CategoryAccounts
    .Include(x => x.Accounts)
    .Include(x => x.Owner)
    .ToList();
//Clear with ForEach

//Clear Accounts poperty to null
//Accounts is List<Acccount>
ret.ForEach(x => x.Accounts = null);
//Clear Owner poperty to null
//Owner is class Owner 
ret.ForEach(x => x.Owner = null);
```

Comment: great catch! I wonder does this only happen with FKey relationships?

Comment: Correct. Basically any complex/custom type inside your DbContext will work like this.

Comment: So after this code `//In result is still ret[0].Account != null`? It's ridiculous that no one made any comment about this. The OP seems to show his problem after `//In result`, you copied his exact comment showing his  problem. And now it really looks like the code does nothing. While I would expect it should be `//In result ret[0].Account == null;`

Comment: You are right, OP added those two lines illustrate problem. I accidentally copied them and included in my answer where they don't belong. Updated my answer.